# How to change one element in a sublist using list comprhension

Tags: python, list

I am worrying in python, and I've a list composed by 8 sublists, made in this way: [[value1,value2,value3], ...].

I want to change to "False" only the third value (value3) in all sublists using a list comprhension, but my code does not work, and a I don't know why.

```py
[[a, b, False] for a, b, _ in athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first']]
```

`athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first']` is the list of sublists.

Comment: In all sublists

Comment: This code works for me. What is the issue?

Comment: What? In my code all old values remains in the previous configuration. Just checked

Comment: Did you assign the result? `athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first'] = [...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
athlete_session_el = {}
athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first'] = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

print([[sublist[0], sublist[1], False] for sublist in athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first'] ])

[[1, 2, False], [1, 2, False], [1, 2, False]]
```

Comment: Ok yes, it works. But only if in athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first'] i've this kind of sublists [(x,y,z)].. I've this ones [x,y,z], and "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" raises

Comment: print([[sublist[0], sublist[1], False] for sublist in athlete_session_el['top_bottom_first'] ]) works with [x,y,z]. I'll edit the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
liste= [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
comp = [False if indx ==2 else y for x in liste for indx, y in enumerate(x) ]
```